# importing content from text file into the main python file

Tags: python

So i am working on a project for my ap class and I am having trouble impoting a text file in vs code. I have in total 5 files in a folder of which two are text and rest are python file. I have a file named maincode.py which has all my code and when i try to import the text file using the code

`with open("textFile.txt") as file:` readTextFile = file.read()
`text= list(map(str, readTextFile.split()))`

it keeps saying there is no directory which has such name. can someone help me with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the file in the same directory as your python script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, and [format your code correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so that we can see how you indented it. Also, make sure you understand the terminology you are using - what you are trying to do with this code *is not* called "importing" it. You should also make sure you understand the concept of a *current working directory* - if you don't immediately recognize that term, look it up in a search engine before you do anything else.